# Integrating Azure AD with Google Apps

Tags: azure, g-suite, entra-id

I have been looking into this guide to integrate Google Apps with Azure AD: https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/active-directory-saas-google-apps-tutorial/

But, there are a few issues.

My accounts are in Google Apps and Azure AD are empty since I just started using Azure AD, can I migrate the other way around?
I also have three different domains, all authorized and ready in Google Apps and Azure AD.

I would love to create logins/entries in Azure AD that matches the email address in Google Apps and sync them that way, is that possible? I don't want to "reset" users accounts in Google Apps and risk that I remove or recreate mailboxes.

Comment: Good question! but I really dont think its dooable, why? because even on azure some service dont sync account between them.